# Rails migrate cronjobs to whenever

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, rake, whenever

On server we have the following cronfile:

```
MAILTO=admin_email@project.com
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /path/to/project/folder;RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake some_rake_task'
0 */2 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /path/to/project/folder;RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake another_rake_task'
# and so on
```

I had no problems with moving it to [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever):

`config/schedule.rb`:

```
every '* * * * *' do
  rake 'some_rake_task', output: 'log/cron.log'
end
every '0 */2 * * *' do
  rake 'another_rake_task', output: 'log/cron.log'
end
# and so on
```

The question is how do I implement MAIL_TO option in whenever, so that when anything goes wrong admin is getting notified?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would set up error notifications with [Airbrake](https://airbrake.io/) or [Rollbar](https://rollbar.com/?dr) which can both be configured to notify of errors within Rake tasks. That way you'll get notified automatically when something goes wrong in your CRON jobs.

Comment: we have airbrake/errbit established. The issue with that is that too much people are getting notifications from errbit, and about rake task failures we need to notify only few devs.

Comment: Ah, I see. Are you using Capistrano for deployment?

Comment: yeap, we use Capistrano

Comment: This discussion seems to be relevant to your situation:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/whenever-gem/Tu15VxJ6ctQ/JqFemcJYo-wJ
Have you seen it?

Comment: I have seen [this one](https://github.com/javan/whenever/issues/60) :) Do you think passing an array of emails would work? `env :MAILTO, [email1, email2]` ?